Generating LaTeX in a chunk vignette gives bad breaks in displayed math
I have a function, symbolicMatrixin the matlib package, https://friendly.github.io/matlib/
which creates the LaTeX for matrices,
https://friendly.github.io/matlib/reference/symbolicMatrix.html,
e.g.,
> symbolicMatrix("a", nrow = "m", ncol="n", matrix="bmatrix")
\begin{bmatrix} 
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
  a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}

It works fine in a simple chunk -- this gives the product A x displayed nicely:
```{r symbMat, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
symbolicMatrix("a", nrow = "m", ncol="n", matrix="bmatrix")
symbolicMatrix("x", nrow = "n", ncol=1)
```


But if I try a more complicated example, I get a bad break in the equation that is displayed in a vignette.
```{r symbMat, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
symbolicMatrix("a", nrow = "m", ncol="n", matrix="bmatrix")
symbolicMatrix("x", nrow = "n", ncol=1)
cat("\\quad=\\quad")
symbolicMatrix("b", nrow = "m", ncol=1)
```

Gives:

I think the problem has to do with the entire "asis" output of the chunk not being treated as display math, but I don't know how to change the function or the call so it renders correctly.
Is there some knitr magic I've overlooked?
To be clear, the following display math works fine  in the vignette, which is exactly the output result of the chunk code displayed at the console:
$$
\begin{bmatrix} 
  a_{11} & a_{12} & \cdots & a_{1n} \\ 
  a_{21} & a_{22} & \cdots & a_{2n} \\ 
  \vdots & \vdots &        & \vdots \\ 
  a_{m1} & a_{m2} & \cdots & a_{mn} \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
  x_{1} \\ 
  x_{2} \\ 
  \vdots \\ 
  x_{n} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
\quad=\quad
\begin{pmatrix} 
  b_{1} \\ 
  b_{2} \\ 
  \vdots \\ 
  b_{m} \\ 
\end{pmatrix}
$$


The problem was that the equations were not wrapped in \begin{equation} ... \end{equation} or $$ .. $$.
I wrote a wrapper function, Eqn() that handles this, no now my test case looks like this as a code chunk

```{r symbMat, results='asis'}
Eqn(symbolicMatrix("a", nrow = "m", ncol="n", matrix="bmatrix"),
    symbolicMatrix("x", nrow = "n", ncol=1),
    cat("\\quad=\\quad"),
    symbolicMatrix("b", nrow = "m", ncol=1))
```

This gives the desired result:

This is now in the development version of the matlib package,
https://friendly.r-universe.dev/matlib
